# substring(string, i .. j) or equivalent in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, dataset

Could anyone please assist on the implementation of a

```
substring(string, i .. j)
```

or equivalent operation on a dataset array?

To illustrate my point a column contains:

```
++WPKennummer++
---------------
'FZPQ5'
---------------
....
---------------
```

and I'd specifically like to do

```
if dt.WPKennummer{1} contains 'FZ' && double(dt.WPKennummer{1})==5
then ...
end
```

Best,

Comment: What should the function do? What's the input and desired output? Post a minimal example

Comment: An illustration has been provided within the post. In a nutshell, check 1/if the content of a dataset cell contains specific character (here 'FZ')  2/ as well as ensure its length =5, here `double(dt.WPKennummer{1})==5`

Comment: With `ETL tool` I will do in 1/ `string.substring( dt.WPKennummer{1}) =='FZ'` but look for an equivalent in `MATLAB`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't understand your example. What is the expected output? Can you describe the intended functionality?

Comment: @Daniel: to make it simple there is not a 'proper' output as I just like to ensure that the described  `if..end _[condition]_` is met in before carrying out with _adhoc_ calculations (database query, etc.). For further simplications maybe it's worth re-phrasing, suppose you have a `string` variable `a='ijkl'` how do you check if the first 2 characters of a ='ij'?

Comment: @LuisMendo && Daniel: i found an existing function in Java too [see] (http://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-string-handling.html) with the following `string` method `myString.substring(0, 3)`. Thus, I Would be delighted to know an equivalent in Matlab.

Comment: Matlab `strings` are really simple `char` arrays. As arrays, they can be indexed exactly like any other array in Matlab. Ex: `str = 'begin middle end' ;` then `str(7:12)='middle'`

Comment: @Hoki: thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing purposes:

```
dt.WPKennummer{1}(1:2)
```

results in

```
'FZ'
```

. Thus this *statement* could be used in any loop.